Pest Identification in SF
First time growing in SF and I have a multitude of different plant varieties in a garden bed. My peas are all growing fine as is my broccoli, but something keeps eating the leaves of my arugula and basil. I can’t figure out what it is. I set out Beer traps and only caught a single Roly Poly bug, no snails or slugs. Thoughts on what this could be?? And what to do?
Thanks so much

Pictures of the damage please

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@YosefBaskin please don't provide half an answer in a comment
